# Find all the PDFs with at least three characters in their name

Tags: find

I'd like to find the PDF files whose name (excluding the extension) is greater than three.

```
$ find ~ -iregex ".{3,}/.pdf"
```

returns nothing, but

```
$ find ~ -iregex ".+/.pdf"
```

works.

How can I enable the `{3,}` variant?

Comment: What length? Filename length? Page length?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming you’re using GNU `find` (which you probably are, since `-iregex` is a GNU extension to [POSIX `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html)), `-regex` and `-iregex` default to Emacs regular expressions, which don’t recognise `{3,}`. You need to specify a different type of regular expressions using the `-regextype` option; in addition, you need to adjust your regular expression to the fact that the expression matches against the full path:

```
find ~ -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*/[^/]{3,}.pdf'
```

You should also escape the `.` so that it matches “.” rather than any character:

```
find ~ -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*/[^/]{3,}\.pdf'
```

The regular expression can be simplified since we only care about three non-“/” characters:

```
find ~ -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*[^/]{3}\.pdf'
```

---

For completeness, with FreeBSD or NetBSD `find` (another implementation that supports `-iregex`, not yours though as `.+` wouldn't work there without `-E`), you'd write:

```
find ~ -iregex '.*[^/]\{3\}\.pdf'
```

or:

```
find -E ~ -iregex '.*[^/]{3}\.pdf'
```

Without `-E`, that's *basic regular expression* (like in `grep`) and with `-E` *extended regular expression* (like in `grep -E`).

With ast-open's `find`:

```
find ~ -iregex '.*[^/]{3}\.pdf'
```

(that's extended regexps out of the box).

Answer (score 20):

Here it's easier with standard wildcards:

```
find ~ -name '*???.[pP][dD][fF]'
```

Or with some `find` implementations (those that support `-regex` also support `-iname`):

```
find ~ -iname '*???.pdf'
```

For arbitrary numbers of characters instead of `3`, that's where you may prefer to revert to `-iregex` where available (see [@Stephen Kitt's answer](/a/443189)) or you could use `zsh` or `ksh93` globs:

- `zsh`:

  ```
  set -o extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
  printf '%s\n' ~/**/?(#c3,).(#i)pdf(D)
  ```

  (the `(D)` to consider hidden files and files in hidden dirs like with `find`)

  - `(#cx,y)` is the `zsh` wildcard equivalent of regexp `{x,y}`
  - `(#i)` for case insensitive
  - `?` standard wildcard for any single character (like regexp `.`)
  - `**/`: any level of subdirectories (including 0)
- `ksh93`:

  ```
  FIGNORE='@(.|..)' # to consider hidden files
  set -o globstar
  printf '%s\n' **/{3,}(?).~(i:pdf)
  ```

  - `@(x|y)`: extended ksh wildcard operator similar to regexp `(x|y)`.
  - `FIGNORE`: special variable which controls what files are ignored by globs. When set, the usual ignoring of hidden files is not done, but we still want to ignore the `.` and `..` directory entries where present.
  - `{x,y}(z)` is `ksh93`'s equivalent of regexp `z{x,y}`.
  - `~(i:...)`: case-insensitive matching.

Globs have some extra advantages over `find` here in that you get a sorted list (you can disable that sorting in `zsh` with the `oN` glob qualifier, or use different sorting criteria) and also work when filenames contain sequence of bytes that don't form valid characters (for instance, in a locale using the UTF-8 charset, the `find` approach would fail to report a `$'St\xE9phane Chazelas - CV.pdf` as that `\xE9` being not a character is not matched by regexp `.` or wildcard `?` or `*` with GNU `find`).

Comment: Would this work for Bash? `shopt -s dotglob globstar; printf '%s\n' ~/**/*???.[pP][dD][fF]`

Answer (score 7):

### How do I know they're PDFs?

You don't unless you ask. Sure, I'm being pedantic, but you didn't ask about *files with `.pdf` in their names*. Just because a file has the characters `.pdf` in the filename *does not make it a PDF file*.

In fact, let's be all-the-way pedantic about this: if the last four characters of a file's name are `.pdf`, then *it will always have more than three characters in its name*.

So doing this *the wrong way*, you might say:

```
$ find . -type f -name "*???.pdf"
./Documents/McLaren 720s Coupe:Order Summary.pdf
./Documents/Setup_MagicISO.exe.pdf
```

See that second one? It's actually an executable. (I know, I changed the name.) And I'm also missing a PDF I *coulda sworn* was in the Documents directory...

```
$ ls Documents
McLaren 720s Coupe:Order Summary.pdf
Pioneer Premier DEH-P490IB CD Install Manual.PDF
Setup_MagicISO.exe.pdf
```

So using `-iname` we could find that one, but that's still turning up this not-a-PDF file.

What we *really* want to do in this case is examine the file's **magic number** using the `file` command. One option outputs the **MIME type**, which is simpler to parse. The `find` query then becomes a simple `-name "???*"`.

```
$ find . -type f -name "???*" -print0|xargs -0 file --mime
./.bash_history:                                              text/plain; charset=us-ascii
./.bash_logout:                                               text/plain; charset=us-ascii
./.bashrc:                                                    text/plain; charset=us-ascii
./.profile:                                                   text/plain; charset=us-ascii
./Documents/McLaren 720s Coupe:Order Summary.pdf:             application/pdf; charset=binary
./Documents/Pioneer Premier DEH-P490IB CD Install Manual.PDF: application/pdf; charset=binary
./Documents/Setup_MagicISO.exe.pdf:                           application/x-dosexec; charset=binary
./Downloads/Setup_MagicISO.exe:                               application/x-dosexec; charset=binary
./Downloads/WindowsUpdate.diagcab:                            application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed; charset=binary
```

Let's use the colon delimiter, and look for MIME type `application/pdf`, then zero out that portion and print the result. Take note, one of my files has a colon in the name; so I can't just ask awk to `($2==":"){print $1}`.

```
$ find . -type f -name "???*" -print0|xargs -0 file --mime|awk -F: '($NF~"application/pdf"){OFS=":";$NF="";print}'|sed s/:$//
./Documents/McLaren 720s Coupe:Order Summary.pdf
./Documents/Pioneer Premier DEH-P490IB CD Install Manual.PDF
```

Now let's finish up by contriving to include PDF files named `a` and `abc`:

```
$ mkdir Documents/other
$ cp -a Documents/McLaren\ 720s\ Coupe\:Order\ Summary.pdf Documents/other/a
$ cp -a Documents/Pioneer\ Premier\ DEH-P490IB\ CD\ Install\ Manual.PDF  Documents/other/abc
$ find . -type f -name "???*" -print0|xargs -0 file --mime|awk -F: '($NF~"application/pdf"){OFS=":";$NF="";print}'|sed s/:$//
./Documents/McLaren 720s Coupe:Order Summary.pdf
./Documents/Pioneer Premier DEH-P490IB CD Install Manual.PDF
./Documents/other/abc
```

That's all. I know I'll probably get dinged for being horribly pedantic, but *in my job* with thousands of NFS volumes to hunt and all kinds of poorly-named files, I wish more people would be pedantic.

Edited to add: in the real world, I might want to make use of `updatedb` to build a searchable file index, `locate` instead of `find` to read that index, and `parallel` instead of `xargs` to thread 'er up. That's somewhat outside the scope of this question though. I wrote that with a straight face, too.  Why do I care so much? I might be looking for movie and audio files; or certain types of photographs; or binary executables in a project data directory.

Comment: _If_ the asker has the same situation you do, where there are PDF files whose names don't end in `.pdf`, then your pedantry will be much appreciated. But it's a relatively unusual situation (your job notwithstanding) and we don't have any reason to believe that the asker actually has to deal with that, so I do think the point you're making, while valid, is kind of distracting - and I think the forceful way you've phrased it pushes the answer into the realm of "(probably) not useful". (My opinion only, of course.)

Comment: Since we’re being pedantic, how would you handle PDFs such as the [PoC||GTFO](https://www.alchemistowl.org/pocorgtfo/) polyglots?

Comment: @StephenKitt - Unsure what you're asking but I'm intrigued. They look like ordinary PDFs to me with not particularly funky names. Would these fail my suggested solution?

Comment: @DavidZ I'm not sure what to say to that. I mean, isn't it a bit pedantic to point out I'm being pedantic when I've already said as much? Here's why it's not "not useful": a good solution for finding PDFs _should be_ an adaptable solution for finding scripts, binary executables, libraries, media files, etc. I can't even begin to see how I'd adapt one of the other answers for "compressed Mach executables", but I'm willing to learn.

Comment: The point of my comment was not to say that you're being pedantic (which you did point out); my point was to explain why I think this answer isn't useful to the OP. I don't think it necessarily needs a response, though (from my perspective) there was a chance that you'd edit your answer based on my feedback.

Comment: @DavidZ Okay, cool. I don't think the OP needs quite _that_ much handholding. I mean, he's getting what he paid for...

Comment: @Rich many of the PDFs are also ZIP files, some are also images, or even bootable virtual machines... (See the “spoilers” links on the first few issues for hints; the rest are documented in the PDFs themselves.)